How to alter field length of a Unique column via Prisma migration (mysql)?
I'm looking to increase the column length of a varchar field. Pretty simple, I have done it before with no issues but I'm having errors this time and I'm thiking it's because this is a Unique tagged column.
this is the prisma schema:
email   String      @unique @db.VarChar(128) /// from 80 to 120

this is the migration.sql
-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `email` VARCHAR(128);

and this is the error I got:
´´´
 migrate found failed migrations in the target database, new migrations will not be applied. Read more about how to resolve migration issues in a production database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve
The `202405133507_alter_users_email_field_length` migration started at 2024-05-16 15:17:44.206 UTC failed

´´´

Have you tried to alter the column before trying to migrate so the data is already in the correct format so it doesn't need to  convert?  Also have you looked at this link yet ->  https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve

What happens if you execute the sql statement manually?

That is what I am curious about as well.

there was an error in my procedure.

There was an error in my procedure. I'll explain:
I created a folder and manually created the ´migration.sql´  file.
what I should have done:
make the length update to the prisma file, and then run:
npx prisma migrate


That is literally the suggestion I had in the comment to your question.  If the suggestion worked, why was there no response so someone that helped could type up this answer instead?  Shrug.
